# Default schema in procedures

Tags: schema, procedure, db2-luw, ibm-data-studio

I'm trying to deploy stored procedure in IBM DATA STUDIO.
I'm using DB2 for LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows).
Stored procedure is in schema X and tables are in Y schema.

I get error

> X.PROCEDURE_NAME is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.13.111,

because deploy assumes that it should use X for table objects being used in 
procedure body.

How can define QUALIFIER for objects used in procedure ?

I've tried

```
SET SCHEMA Y;
```

and some similar variations.
Error is the same.

Can I somehow accomplish this ?

Maybe with precompile options?

[image]

If yes, what should I enter ?

We are using DB2 LUW for a long time, 
and we must always fully qualify table names in stored procedures,
which is annoying.